# MPU6050 stuck on same values while getting the angle as output

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050

I am trying get the rotation value from MPU6050. I am using an Arduino Uno board.

My connections are:

```
MPU6050  Arduino

VCC    ->  5V
GND    ->  GND
SCL    ->  A5
SDA    ->  A4
INT    ->  2
```

The code I am using is:

```
#include <MPU6050_tockn.h>

#include <Wire.h>

MPU6050 mpu6050(Wire);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Wire.begin();

  mpu6050.begin();

  mpu6050.calcGyroOffsets(true);

}


void loop() {

  mpu6050.update();

  Serial.print("angleX : ");

  Serial.print(mpu6050.getAngleX());

  Serial.print("\tangleY : ");

  Serial.print(mpu6050.getAngleY());

  Serial.print("\tangleZ : ");

  Serial.println(mpu6050.getAngleZ());

  delay(4000);

}
```

On my serial monitor I am always getting -35.26, 35.26, -0.0 values. What should I do?